# How to create a function that scores ngrams before unigrams in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, module, sentiment-analysis, vader

Let's assume I would like to score `text` with a dictionary called `dictionary`:

```
text = "I would like to reduce carbon emissions"

dictionary = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["like","reduce","carbon","emissions","reduce carbon emissions"],'score': [1,-1,-1,-1,1]})
```

I would like to write a function that adds up every term in `dictionary` that is in `text`. However, such a rule must have a nuance: prioritizing ngrams over unigrams.

Concretely, if I sum up the unigrams in `dictionary` that are in `text`, I get: `1+(-1)+(-1)+(-1)=-2` since `like =1, reduce=-1, carbon =-1,emissions=-1`. This is not what I want. The function must say the following things:

1. consider first ngrams (`reduce carbon emissions` in the example), if there the set of ngrams is not empty, then attribute the corresponding value to it, otherwise if the the set of ngrams is empty then consider unigrams;
2. if the set of ngrams is non-empty, ignore those single words (unigrams) that are in the selected ngrams (e.g. ignore "reduce", "carbon" and "emissions" that are already in "reduce carbon emissions").

Such a function should give me this output: `+2` since `like =1` + `reduce carbon emissions = 1`.

I am pretty new  to Python and I am stuck. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use DataFrame for this?

Comment: Unfortunate answer: I have been using python for a week for NLP, so I guess using what I would use in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sort the keywords descendingly by length, so it's guarantee that `re` would match ngrams before one-gram:

```
import re

pat = '|'.join(sorted(dictionary.text, key=len, reverse=True))

found = re.findall(fr'\b({pat})\b', text)
```

Output:

```
['like', 'reduce carbon emissions']
```

To get the expected output:

```
scores = dictionary.set_index('text')['score']

scores.re_index(found).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I am wrong but `re` seems to embed my condition 2 as well right? Meaning it automatically excludes unigrams contained in the selected ngram. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the pattern is searched left to right, and greedy. If it finds the longer substring, that part is not search again.

Comment: would you mind adding a line of code where the score of the selected words is added (1+1=2)? It would be great

Comment: @Rollo99 see updated answer.